# MOSFET drain-source voltage in an H-bridge

Tags: mosfet, dc-motor, h-bridge

[image][image]

I'm using an H-bridge to drive a DC motor.

The H-bridge is driven by sign-magnitude method (i.e. one of half bridges is not switching.)

I did the best I could but I couldn't figure out what's happening in the picture.

CH1 is the drain voltage, and CH3 is the gate voltage of the low side MOSFET with respect to source.

About 5 A is flowing through the motor.

Since I used typical 1 mΩ Rds(on) MOSFET (TPH1R405PL,L1Q), I expected **negative** 5 mV on drain-source, which is true on the other half bridge. But on the switching side my oscilloscope shows about 600mV drain-source voltage and it is not even negative.

Comment: Schematic please.

Comment: The drain of a low side FET will be above the source so why do you expect a negative voltage?  Are you really driving the gate to 15 volts as the scope appears to show?  What is the identity of the FET?  Is the source actually grounded or does it sit on top of a current sense resistor?

Comment: added Schematic and identity of the FET.

Comment: I expect a negative voltage because the current will flow source to drain of lowside FET of switching side.

Comment: The electron current, sure but electrons are negative.  The drain voltage will be above the source.   Probe the source, too.  Either the fet isn't all the way on, or much of your drop is in the sense resistor, which may be incorrectly sized.

Comment: since my power supply is isolated,I connected ground probe directly to the source.so,I assume drop in the sense resistor is irrelevant.considering gate voltage is 15V(way above threshold),is that possible the fet isn't all the way on?also I meant positive current.since the current flow through motor can't change,it has to flow body diode.and then once fet is on ,it'll flow channel instead of body diode.is that correct?